# Controller view Spring MVC connection

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I Have this controller , that is giving me a result  in the console , 
and the view showing the  result written directly in the jsp page .
no error is showing and 
 I think the problem is in the configuration  files .
Here is the Controller

```
@Controller
public class ListController {

    final String inputFileName = "Onto.owl";
    String categorie = "Mode";
    String nom = "HasName";
    String description= "HasDescription";

//  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
//  public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
//          HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
// 
//      
// 
//      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
//      modelAndView.addObject("pList", GetAllFonction.displayy());
// 
//      return modelAndView;
//  }
//  


       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
           String st="Hello Spring MVC Framework!";
          model.addAttribute("message",st );
          return "hello";


}



}
```

and the view list.jsp

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>${message}</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>birth</th>
<!--                <th>actions</th> -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

That is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      jsp/index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I can't locate the problem

Comment: You return hello but are using a file called list.jsp. return "list" instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
       String st="Hello Spring MVC Framework!";
      model.addAttribute("message",st );
      return "list";
```

}